# Column-rule Property in Firefox creates wrong color result

Tags: html, css

When I use the column-rule Property in FF it looks as if the column separating line consited of 2 colors. In Chrome it looks fine. How can I achieve to have a result like in Chrome?

example:

[column-rule Property wrong in ff](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-rule)

```
    -webkit-column-rule: 4px outset #ff00ff; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-rule: 4px outset #ff00ff; /* Firefox */
    column-rule: 4px outset #ff00ff;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `columns-rule-style` property to `solid`...

```
-webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
-moz-column-rule-style: solid;
column-rule-style: solid;
```

It looks as though Firefox uses a default value of `ridge` or `groove`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyv1cqrs/1/)